# Why doesn's naming coordinate with \foreach iterator work inside axis environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, loops, coordinates

Without the axis environment, we can write something like this

```
\documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
       \draw (rnd, rnd) -- (rnd, rnd) coordinate (name\i);
       \node at (name\i) {name\i};
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The coordinate name `name\i` is properly substituted by `name1`, `name2`, and `name3`. However, inside a `axis` environment, it doesn't work. Take this MWE as an example:

```tex
\documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \foreach \w in {1,2,...,3} {
        \addplot[blue, mark=square, ycomb] coordinates {(\w, \w^2 - 1)}
          coordinate (test\w);
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

it yields

> Undefined control sequence.  test\w

Comment: `\addplot`s and TikZ paths are collected and executed later when everything is setup correctly. This is done by PGFPlots. The same postponing process is not set up for `\foreach`. This is combined with the inner `\addplot` getting this treatment again but the `\w` is not expanded when the path is cached. There are multiple Q&A dealing with that on this site. The solutions involve [`\pgfplotsextra`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/path-operations#pgfp.%3CCS%3Epgfplotsextra), [`\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/utility-commands), expansion control or other tricks to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Qrrbrbirlbel noted in a comment, one of the ways to deal with the issue is expansion control.  Here is how it might be done for the example given:

```
\documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \foreach \w in {1,2,...,3} {
        \edef\z{coordinates  {(\w, \w^2 - 1)} coordinate (test\w)}
        \def\tmp{\addplot[blue, mark=square, ycomb]}
        \expandafter\tmp\z;
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this way, the `\addplot` is provided with the expanded values of `\w` at each step in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be

```tex
\documentclass[beamer,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3}{
            \addplot[blue, mark=square, ycomb] coordinates {(#1, {#1^2 - 1})};
            \edef\temp{\noexpand\coordinate (test#1) at (axis cs:#1,{#1^2 - 1});}
            \temp
        }
    \end{axis}

    Access the coordinates after the axis environment
    \foreach \w in {1,2,3} {
        \node at (test\w) {test\w};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look in the manual of `pgfplots` for `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,...,3} {
        \addplot[blue, mark=square, ycomb] coordinates {(#1, #1^2 - 1)}
          coordinate (test#1);
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]